Chromium Remembers Login Info Despite Being Setup as New Page
Framework: Nodejs, Angular, Typescript
Reference from Playwright:
https://playwright.dev/docs/auth/#Automate%20Logging%20in#
I'm trying to setup an authentication for all my tests in playwright. In the playwright's reference, they used a json file but I use process.env.VARIABLES instead. Everything seems fine until the step await loginPage.login(); where Chromium somehow remembers my login info and used that.
I thought that doing this will force Chromium to start a fresh page instead?
  const pageContext: BrowserContext = await browser.newContext();
  const newPage: Page = await pageContext.newPage();

auth.setup.ts
import { BrowserContext, Page, test as setup } from '@playwright/test';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login-page';
import * as Consts from '../helpers/application-content';

const authFile = '../../data/user.json';

setup('Authenticate', async ({ browser }) => {
  const pageContext: BrowserContext = await browser.newContext();
  const newPage: Page = await pageContext.newPage();

  // Perform authentication steps.
  await newPage.goto(`${process.env.TARGET}${process.env.LANGUAGE}`);

  const loginPage: LoginPage = new LoginPage(newPage);
  await newPage.waitForURL(/login.microsoftonline.com/, { waitUntil: Consts.DOM_CONTENT_LOAD });

  // Log into BEST 2.0 app
  await loginPage.login();

  // BEST 2.0 Home page
  await newPage.waitForURL(process.env.LANGUAGE, { waitUntil: Consts.DOM_CONTENT_LOAD });

  //await newPage.context().storageState({ path: authFile });
});

playwright.config.ts
import { defineConfig, devices } from '@playwright/test';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import path from 'path';

/**
 * Read environment variables from file.
 * 1. https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv
 * 2. https://playwright.dev/docs/test-parameterize
 */
dotenv.config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, '.', 'playwright-settings.env') });

/**
 * Reference: See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration for more information
 * 1. Test Report: https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters
 * 2. Test Options: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions
 * 3. Trace Setting: https://playwright.dev/docs/trace-viewer
 * 4. Test CLI: https://playwright.dev/docs/test-cli
 */
export default defineConfig({
  globalSetup: './playwright-setup.js',

  testDir: '.',
  testIgnore: ['test-gen.spec.ts'],

  timeout: 4 * 60 * 1000, // Global timeout per test case = 3 minutes

  forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
  retries: 2,
  workers: process.env.CI ? 3 : undefined,
  fullyParallel: false, // One worker runs on each .spec.ts file

  reporter: [
    ['junit', { outputFile: 'test-results/results.xml' }],
    ['html', { outputFolder: 'playwright-test-results' }]
  ],

  use: {
    // Using `await page.goto('/')` in code will go to the baseURL stated below
    baseURL: `${process.env.TARGET}${process.env.LANGUAGE}`,

    // Collect tracing (images) after failing the first time
    trace: 'on-first-retry'
  },

  projects: [
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
        // Use prepared auth state.
        //storageState: './data/user.json',
        launchOptions: { args: ['--auth-server-allowlist="*"'] }
      },
      dependencies: ['setup']
    },
    // Setup project
    { name: 'setup', testMatch: /.*\.setup\.ts/ }
  ]
});

